# differential of the projection is itself

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, differential

**Suppose $\pi:M\times N\to M$ defined by $\pi(x,y)=x\ ,\forall (x,y)\in M\times N$ where $M,N$ are smooth manifolds of dimension m and n respectively. To prove that differential of $\pi$ is itself.**

My try:
In local coordinates Jacobian of $\pi$ is $\begin{bmatrix} I_m & 0\end{bmatrix}_{m\times (m+n)}$. From here how can I conclude?

Comment: The differential cannot be $\pi$, since $\pi:M\times N\to N$ while $d\pi:T(M\times N)\to TN$

Comment: Caffeine has almost said it all. But just a few more words: the differential $\mathrm{d}\pi$ is, in some sense, linear. So it could not be the same thing as $\pi$ itself.

Comment: I wonder whether you confused the general case with a more restricted one? If the context were that of a linear map $\pi : \mathbb R^{m+n} \approx \mathbb R^m \times \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ then it would actually make some sense to say that the differential of $\pi$ is itself.